# Magento : Is there anything missing? if I am adding this script in head.phtml then page is not rendered well in IE. My code as below

Tags: magento

```
 if(preg_match('/(?i)msie /',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){ ?> 
    <link href=" echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/custom-ie-specific-style.css') " 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

---

I want to add this stylesheet only for IE browser. Also added file in `skin/css` folder 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance..'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing directly in head.phtml you can add the CSS with IE condition using page.xml (app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout) as below :

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <name>css/styles-ie.css</name>
    <params/>
    <if>lt IE 8</if>
</action>
```

Let me know if you need further explanations or help.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still not working. I just want to target IE 8,9. Have tried idea suggested by you early but bad luck..... I have not enough reputation otherwise I can vote up your answer..

Comment: I have also tried dynamically adding css file from jquery but not linked in IE other browser work fine....

Comment: You can always verify my answer. Did you tried adding it through xml as I shown ? Clear cache and you will be able to see it in page source.

Comment: Yes I did but don't know why it's not working it should but right now I have used this link "http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/" and it's worked fine for me

Comment: Okay understandable that you use media hacks, but ideally above does work. If you see in default Magento a bit more closely you will find a css styles-ie.css added in the same manner.

Comment: I have also added style in the "styles-ie.css" but no change the file was loading but not affect in IE..Thanks Bhai for your help @Chiragit007

Comment: Ohh I see no worry. In the ideal world, if you place css in there it works generally. Nevertheless glad it worked for you. You can vote up or verify my answer if you feel.

Comment: I can't vote up, not enough reputation But I will try to verify answer after searching how to verify ans in stackoverflow.... :-) @chiragit007